# Why is my variable displaying incorrect value in Laravel 5.4 Blade file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a variable `$country_code` that is displaying the correct value in one part of my form but not in a different part. Why is this happening?

This is my code:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['PinVerificationController@valid'],'id'=>'pin_code_form']) }}
    //$country_code shows 1
    We sent a text message to {{$country_code}} {{$phone_number}}. You should receive it within a few seconds.<br><br>
    {{ Form::label('Pin Code', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('country_code', $country_code) }}//<------shows 1-US instead of 1
    {{ Form::hidden('phone_number', $phone_number) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('type', $pin_notification_type) }}
    {{ Form::text('pin_code', null,['placeholder' => 'Pin Code'])}}<br><br>
    Enter a 4 digit pin you received by phone.
    <br>
    <br>
    {{ Form::submit('Verify',['name'=>'validate'])}}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

So if I set $country_code to "1" in my controller it'll display **We sent a text message to 1 5555555. You should receive it within a few seconds.**
But if I do an inspect element on my hidden form it displays 1-US. I've tried `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled` but the problem still persists.

I've also tried hardcoding a value `{{ Form::hidden('country_code', 'asdf') }}` and i'm not seeing the change. I tried adding a test `{{ Form::hidden('country_code1', 'asdf') }}` and see the update.

I also renamed `country_code` to `country_code111` for my hidden field and it displayed the correct value of 1. I thought it was a caching issue but like I mentioned I've tried `php artisan cache:clear` and the problem is still there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you try it without the `Form::` helper, ie `<input type="hidden" name="country_code" value="{{ $country_code }}"/>` does it work then? This kinda sounds like caching, but doesn't sounds right.

Comment: @TimLewis with your code it did display the 999

Comment: Well that's unexpected. Personally, I don't use the `Form::` helpers in my code (more typing, but more control I find), so that's an option if you're ok with it. Otherwise, I'm not sure. Let me see if I can recreate.

Comment: @TimLewis I renamed my hidden form to `code_country` and everything works fine. I see the correct value. This is really weird.

Comment: *Shrug* No idea then. Keep an eye on it I guess? If it keeps happening then investigate further.

Comment: Try php artisan view:clear and php artisan optimize

Comment: @RutvijKothari That didn't work

Comment: IIRC, `{{ $variable }}` uses the _view's data_ as symbol table, while `{{ ... }}` uses the _current scope's_ symbol table. Look for a variable named `$country_code` in your view's code stack, and I bet it has a a value of `1-US` (if I had to guess, it looks like a `<option>` value).

Comment: @bishop how do I look at the view code stack?

Comment: [`debug_print_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) before you dispatch to your view.

Comment: @bishop I am seeing the `1-US` which is incorrect. What do I do with this information though?

Comment: `unset($country_code);` just before dispatching into your view.

Comment: @bishop that didn't work

Comment: Post the complete output of your `debug_print_backtrace`, please.

Comment: is "country_code" in your request data?

Comment: What do u get when u dump all variables using [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)?

Comment: Maybe you use some javascript script which change `country_code` value?

Comment: @yrv16 nope, not doing anything with JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using Laravel 5.4, I assume you are using `Form` from the LaravelCollective, since they were removed from baseline Laravel in 5.x.

LaravelCollective Forms will override the value you provide to the input if it exists in the request data, or in old posted data (the `old()` function). I suspect this is the case for you.

You can see this behavior implementation [here](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.4/src/FormBuilder.php#L1142).

To solve this problem, you have a few options:

1. change the name of the request parameter feeding into the page (if you have control over it)
2. rename your field name to something that doesn't conflict
3. Don't use `Form::` to generate the form and just use classic html/Blade to create the hidden input automatically

Personally, I would recommend #3 because then you have full control over your code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="country_code" value="{{ $country_code }}"/>
```

Comment: if this is the issue, how would I fix it?

Comment: @altoids You either have to a) change the name of the request parameter feeding into the page, b) rename your parameter to something that doesn't conflict c) Don't use Form:: to generate the form and just use classic html to create the hidden input automatically

Comment: please add your comment to your answer via an edit then delete your comment.

Comment: Thanks, I went with option 3 and that fixed it.

Comment: Another option is to not render a view from the same controller that accepts a `POST` request. It is a common best practice to process a POST request, and then redirect to a standard GET page with the result message you wish to share, or in this case, an additional "next step" form. If you've ever refreshed a page and seen a popup asking if you want to submit the form again, that's exactly what's happening here.